# WINC1500 firmware update via serial bridge fails

Tags: serial-port, wifi, firmware, adafruit

I have a WINC1500 SPI to wifi breakout board from adafruit which I am using with STM32f103 microcontroller successfully.
I am trying to update WINC1500 firmware(version 19.5.2->19.7.7) using serial bridge application provided by Microchip:

https://github.com/avrxml/asf/tree/68cddb46ae5ebc24ef8287a8d4c61a6efa5e2848/common/components/wifi/winc1500/serial_bridge_example

I ported this app on a STM32F103 microcontroller.

Microchip provides a windows app to update the firmware using the serial bridge app. Its works like this

Windows host APP -----> UART ----> STM32F103 ---> SPI ---> WINC1500

Link to the windows app
https://github.com/MicrochipTech/WINC-Releases/blob/master/WINC1500/19_7_7/WINC1500_FIRMWARE_UPDATE_PROJECT.7z

Within the Windows App zip there is a bat file which is used to update the firmware

```
download_all_uart.bat  19
```

After execution of above bat file it works ok for a while and I can see some progress in the firmware update sequence but at one point the windows app tries to change the serial baud rate from 115200 to 500000 and at that point STM32F103 returns 00 instead of AC for a request from Windows app. At this point the whole process stops.

Below is the command line log

```
Usage: download_all_uart.bat [optional com port]
Host must be running a serial bridge or ATcmd app
Using COM port 19
Please connect and power up the board.

** Programming attempt 1 of 5...
call download_all.bat UART 3A0 0 19
Mode UART
Chip 3A0
Mode UART
Chip 1500
Updating PLL table in image for 3A0 variant
Press any key to continue . . .
Press any key to continue . . .
firmware\winc_programmer_uart.exe  -p \\.\COM19 -d winc1500 -pfw programmer_firmware\release3A0\programmer_release_text.bin -r efuse -o efuse.tmp -of efuse_active
WINC Programming Tool 2.0.0 [r719] (Aug 13 2021)
Copyright (C) Microchip Technology Inc. 2021

software WINC serial bridge found, baud rate changes supported
chip ID is 0x00050001
programming firmware file: programmer_firmware\release3A0\programmer_release_text.bin
starting device
reinitialise serial bridge to 500000
waiting for firmware to runUnknown response received [0x00]
error: failed to receive read register request ACK
error: failed to initialise programming firmware 'programmer_firmware\release3A0\programmer_release_text.bin' on device
Press any key to continue . . .
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

Below is the log from com port of the whole process

```
:26:43 - Open port COM19 (C:\Users\A1056998\Downloads\IClouldDrive\WINC1500_FIRMWARE_UPDATE_PROJECT\WINC1500_FIRMWARE_UPDATE_PROJECT\src\firmware\firmware\winc_programmer_uart.exe)

:26:43 Written  (COM19)
    12                                                .                
:26:43 Read  (COM19) 
    5b                                                                
:26:43 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 00 e7 00 00 f4 13 00 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.ç..ô.......    
:26:43 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:46 Read  (COM19) 
    00 00 00 01                                       ....             
:26:46 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 00 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............    
:26:46 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:50 Read  (COM19) 
    00 00 00 01                                       ....             
:26:50 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 06 00 00 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............    
:26:50 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:50 Written  (COM19) 
    04 10 00 60 0c 10 74 10 ab a5 00 00 0c 70 68 00   ...`..t.«¥...ph. 
    0c d0 74 00 f2 03 b1 07                           .Ðt.ò.±.         
:26:53 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:53 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 1e 00 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............
:26:53 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:53 Written  (COM19) 
    24 74 c6 7d a2 fd 06 7c 0c 70 74 00 0c 60 74 10   $tÆ}¢ý.|.pt..`t.
    f2 03 b1 07 24 74 c6 76                           ò.±.$tÆv         
:26:56 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:56 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 36 00 30 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.6..0.......    
:26:56 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:56 Written  (COM19) 
    a2 fd 0c e0 68 00 0c b0 68 00 f2 04 30 7e f1 70   ¢ý.àh..°h.ò.0~ñp 
    24 e4 c6 eb a2 fc 08 70                           $äÆë¢ü.p         
:26:59 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:59 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 4e 00 48 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.N..H.......    
:26:59 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:26:59 Written  (COM19) 
    0f 00 11 17 8b 95 00 00 0c 70 68 00 f2 e3 00 00   ....‹•...ph.òã.. 
    06 63 06 53 57 6c 77 54                           .c.SWlwT         
:27:02 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:02 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 66 00 60 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.f..`.......    
:27:02 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:02 Written  (COM19) 
    77 34 08 70 01 30 64 6b 5c 50 00 ff 13 33 2c 70   w4.p.0dk\P.ÿ.3,p 
    00 02 66 65 57 38 b9 47                           ..feW8¹G         
:27:05 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:05 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 7e 00 78 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.~..x.......    
:27:05 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:05 Written  (COM19) 
    08 00 66 63 b9 67 0c 00 0c 60 a5 00 b9 67 10 00   ..fc¹g...`¥.¹g.. 
    0c 60 1f 00 b9 67 14 00                           .`..¹g..         
:27:08 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:08 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 96 00 90 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.–.........    
:27:08 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:08 Written  (COM19) 
    b9 27 1c 00 0c 60 85 00 b9 67 04 00 38 67 00   ¹'...`….¹g..8g.. 
    c4 61 92 fd e1 f0 00 00                           Äa’ýáð..         
:27:12 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:12 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 ae 00 a8 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.®..¨.......    
:27:12 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:12 Written  (COM19) 
    08 70 01 30 2c 70 00 02 b9 07 08 00 04 66 b9 67   .p.0,p..¹....f¹g 
    0c 00 04 61 b9 67 14 00                           ...a¹g..         
:27:15 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:15 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 c6 00 c0 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Æ..À.......    
:27:15 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:15 Written  (COM19) 
    b9 07 1c 00 0c 60 81 00 b9 67 04 00 38 67 00   ¹....`.¹g..8g.. 
    c4 61 92 fd e1 f0 00 00                           Äa’ýáð..         
:27:18 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:18 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 de 00 d8 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Þ..Ø.......    
:27:18 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:18 Written  (COM19) 
    08 70 01 30 2c 70 00 02 04 61 b9 67 08 00 04 55   .p.0,p...a¹g...U 
    b9 57 0c 00 b9 67 14 00                           ¹W..¹g..         
:27:21 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:21 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 f6 00 f0 10 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.ö..ð.......    
:27:21 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:21 Written  (COM19) 
    34 14 08 60 03 00 26 61 b9 67 1c 00 0c 60 81 00   4..`..&a¹g...`. 
    b9 67 04 00 38 67 00                           ¹g..8g..         
:27:24 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:24 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 0f 00 08 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............    
:27:24 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:24 Written  (COM19) 
    c4 61 92 fd 30 21 24 14 33 22 e1 f0 3c 10 10 00   Äa’ý0!$.3"áð<... 
    d1 c1 06 e2 06 d3 06 c4                           ÑÁ.â.Ó.Ä         
:27:27 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:27 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 27 00 20 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.'.. .......    
:27:27 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:27 Written  (COM19) 
    4b 85 00 00 06 6e 06 5e 06 2e 57 6c 77 54 77 24   K…...n.^..WlwTw$ 
    08 70 01 30 64 62 5c 50                           .p.0db\P         
:27:30 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:30 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 3f 00 38 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.?..8.......    
:27:30 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:30 Written  (COM19) 
    00 ff 13 22 2c 70 00 02 66 65 57 28 b9 07 08 00   .ÿ.",p..feW(¹... 
    66 62 b9 67 0c 00 06 4c                           fb¹g...L         
:27:33 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:33 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 57 00 50 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.W..P.......    
:27:33 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:33 Written  (COM19) 
    04 6f b9 67 14 00 57 44 b9 d7 1c 00 6c 40 84 00   .o¹g..WD¹×..l@„. 
    b9 47 04 00 38 67 00                           ¹G..8g..         
:27:36 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:36 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 6f 00 68 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.o..h.......    
:27:36 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:36 Written  (COM19) 
    c4 61 92 fd cb 86 00 00 cb 86 00 00 d4 21 92 fd   Äa’ýË†..Ë†..Ô!’ý 
    08 70 01 30 2c 70 00 02                           .p.0,p..         
:27:39 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:39 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 87 00 80 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.‡..€.......    
:27:39 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:39 Written  (COM19) 
    b9 07 08 00 04 64 b9 67 0c 00 04 61 b9 67 14 00   ¹....d¹g...a¹g.. 
    b9 07 1c 00 0c 60 81 00                           ¹....`.         
:27:42 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:42 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 9f 00 98 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Ÿ..˜.......    
:27:42 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:42 Written  (COM19) 
    b9 67 04 00 38 67 00 c4 61 92 fd 50 c1 2c 10   ¹g..8g..Äa’ýPÁ,. 
    10 00 e1 f0 34 14 08 70                           ..áð4..p         
:27:45 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:45 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 b7 00 b0 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.·..°.......    
:27:45 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:45 Written  (COM19) 
    01 30 b1 01 2c 70 00 02 04 64 b9 67 08 00 1c 60   .0±.,p...d¹g...` 
    61 00 b9 67 0c 00 04 61                           a.¹g...a         
:27:48 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:48 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 cf 00 c8 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Ï..È.......    
:27:48 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:48 Written  (COM19) 
    b9 67 14 00 08 60 03 00 26 61 b9 67 1c 00 0c 60   ¹g...`..&a¹g...` 
    81 00 b9 67 04 00 38 67                           .¹g..8g         
:27:51 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:51 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 e7 00 e0 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.ç..à.......    
:27:51 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:51 Written  (COM19) 
    00 c4 61 92 fd 30 21 24 14 e1 f0 b8 70 6c 00   ..Äa’ý0!$.áð¸pl. 
    34 14 b1 f1 92 0c 6b 8d                           4.±ñ’.k         
:27:54 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:54 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 ff 00 f8 11 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.ÿ..ø.......    
:27:54 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:54 Written  (COM19) 
    00 00 14 71 c6 27 82 07 77 28 24 2f 04 71 53 72   ...qÆ'‚.w($/.qSr 
    b9 70 6c 00 30 f1 38 20                           ¹pl.0ñ8          
:27:57 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:57 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 14 00 10 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............    
:27:57 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:27:57 Written  (COM19) 
    6c 00 24 14 e1 f0 00 00 b8 70 70 00 34 14 b1 f1   l.$.áð..¸pp.4.±ñ 
    92 06 6b 8f 00 00 d7 28                           ’.k..×(         
:28:00 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:00 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 2c 00 28 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.,..(.......    
:28:00 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:00 Written  (COM19) 
    b9 20 70 00 30 f1 38 20 70 00 24 14 e1 f0 00 00   ¹ p.0ñ8 p.$.áð.. 
    08 70 00 30 2c 70 1c 11                           .p.0,p..         
:28:03 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:03 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 44 00 40 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.D..@.......    
:28:03 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:03 Written  (COM19) 
    30 67 14 54 56 65 b1 67 30 67 66 62 b1 67 e1 f0   0g.TVe±g0gfb±gáð 
    93 73 3c 10 14 00 d9 c1                           “s<...ÙÁ         
:28:06 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:06 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 5c 00 58 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.\..X.......    
:28:06 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:06 Written  (COM19) 
    04 00 b1 b1 06 c2 06 d3 06 e4 82 1e 0c b0 00 01   ..±±.Â.Ó.ä‚..°.. 
    36 b7 c6 be 06 4b c2 02                           6·Æ¾.KÂ.         
:28:09 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:09 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 74 00 70 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.t..p.......    
:28:09 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:09 Written  (COM19) 
    06 4e 06 2d 06 3c 23 44 ab 88 00 00 c6 eb a2 12   .N.-.<#D«ˆ..Æë¢. 
    f2 0c cc e0 00 01 06 be                           ò.Ìà...¾         
:28:12 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:12 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 8c 00 88 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Œ..ˆ.......    
:28:12 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:12 Written  (COM19) 
    c2 03 0c b0 00 01 06 2d 06 3c 23 4b ab 88 00 00   Â..°...-.<#K«ˆ.. 
    26 cb 26 db 36 eb c4 e0                           &Ë&Û6ëÄà         
:28:15 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:15 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 a4 00 a0 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.¤.. .......    
:28:15 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:15 Written  (COM19) 
    92 f1 58 c1 04 00 30 b1 04 20 2c 10 14 00 e1 f0   ’ñXÁ..0±. ,...áð 
    3c 10 30 00 d9 c1 20 00                           <.0.ÙÁ .         
:28:18 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:18 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 bc 00 b8 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.¼..¸.......    
:28:18 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:18 Written  (COM19) 
    08 d0 00 30 d9 81 10 00 04 79 2c d0 8c 10 b1 7d   .Ð.0Ù...y,ÐŒ.±} 
    04 23 cb 91 00 00 08 e0                           .#Ë‘...à         
:28:21 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:21 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 d4 00 d0 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Ô..Ð.......    
:28:21 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:21 Written  (COM19) 
    00 60 30 7d c4 77 82 08 c4 78 04 64 b7 93 82 54   .`0}Äw‚.Äx.d·“‚T 
    c4 76 92 f8 f2 0e 0c 70                           Äv’øò..p         
:28:24 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:24 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 ec 00 e8 12 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.ì..è.......    
:28:24 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:24 Written  (COM19) 
    00 30 26 7e 38 2e 0c 30 38 37 10 00 38 4e 08 30   .0&~8..087..8N.0 
    cb 82 00 00 fa d7 00 00                           Ë‚..ú×..         
:28:27 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:27 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 05 00 00 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............    
:28:27 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:27 Written  (COM19) 
    0c c0 00 30 26 ce 38 2e 0c 30 38 3c 10 00 38 4e   .À.0&Î8..08<..8N 
    08 30 0c b0 13 30 8b 92                           .0.°.0‹’         
:28:30 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:30 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 1d 00 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............    
:28:30 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:30 Written  (COM19) 
    00 00 38 3c 10 00 38 6e 04 30 38 4e 08 30 26 be   ..8<..8n.08N.0&¾ 
    0c 70 14 30 13 c6 26 b4                           .p.0.Æ&´         
:28:33 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:33 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 35 00 30 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.5..0.......    
:28:33 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:33 Written  (COM19) 
    26 7e f2 03 91 07 24 71 c6 7b 92 fd 08 70 00 40   &~ò.‘.$qÆ{’ý.p.@ 
    2c 70 ac 07 13 66 08 20                           ,p¬..f.          
:28:36 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:36 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 4d 00 48 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.M..H.......    
:28:36 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:36 Written  (COM19) 
    0d 00 b1 67 2c 20 14 30 cb 82 00 00 0c 70 14 30   ..±g, .0Ë‚...p.0 
    26 7e f2 05 10 67 24 71                           &~ò..g$q         
:28:39 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:39 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 65 00 60 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.e..`.......    
:28:39 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:39 Written  (COM19) 
    13 66 76 c6 c6 7b 92 fb 08 70 00 40 2c 70 ac 07   .fvÆÆ{’û.p.@,p¬. 
    30 57 06 6c 57 64 c4 c0                           0W.lWdÄÀ         
:28:42 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:42 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 7d 00 78 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.}..x.......    
:28:42 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:42 Written  (COM19) 
    66 65 b1 67 04 7c 9a 97 00 00 fa 94 00 00 0c 90   fe±g.|š—..ú”... 
    14 30 08 c0 34 12 0c b0                           .0.À4..°         
:28:45 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:45 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 95 00 90 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.•.........    
:28:45 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:45 Written  (COM19) 
    00 30 26 9e 2c c0 78 56 26 be b1 c9 38 7b 10 00   .0&ž,ÀxV&¾±É8{.. 
    38 6b 08 00 b7 d1 b7 92                           8k..·Ñ·’         
:28:48 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:48 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 ad 00 a8 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.­..¨.......    
:28:48 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:48 Written  (COM19) 
    cb 90 00 00 37 d2 c6 72 82 08 08 a0 01 30 38 81   Ë..7ÒÆr‚.. .08 
    04 00 2c a0 00 02 f2 66                           .., ..òf         
:28:51 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:51 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 c5 00 c0 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Å..À.......    
:28:51 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:51 Written  (COM19) 
    4b 85 00 00 cb 86 00 00 08 70 01 30 91 21 2c 70   K…..Ë†...p.0‘!,p 
    00 02 b9 07 08 00 0c 60                           ..¹....`         
:28:54 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:54 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 dd 00 d8 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Ý..Ø.......    
:28:55 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:55 Written  (COM19) 
    60 00 b9 67 0c 00 04 61 b9 67 14 00 b9 07 1c 00   `.¹g...a¹g..¹... 
    0c 60 81 00 b9 67 04 00                           .`.¹g..         
:28:58 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:58 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 f5 00 f0 13 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.õ..ð.......    
:28:58 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:28:58 Written  (COM19) 
    38 67 00 c4 61 92 fd cb 86 00 00 91 21 cb 86   8g..Äa’ýË†..‘!Ë† 
    00 00 91 21 cb 86 00 00                           ..‘!Ë†..         
:29:01 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:01 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 0a 00 08 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............    
:29:01 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:01 Written  (COM19) 
    d4 21 92 fd 38 3b 10 00 08 20 0d 00 2c 20 14 30   Ô!’ý8;... .., .0 
    04 44 cb 82 00 00 30 69                           .DË‚..0i         
:29:04 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:04 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 22 00 20 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.".. .......    
:29:04 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:04 Written  (COM19) 
    14 71 c6 67 92 39 f2 42 4b 85 00 00 cb 86 00 00   .qÆg’9òBK…..Ë†.. 
    04 4a 26 48 06 64 06 34                           .J&H.d.4         
:29:07 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:07 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 3a 00 38 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.:..8.......    
:29:07 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:07 Written  (COM19) 
    57 6c 77 34 77 44 6c 60 20 00 5c 30 00 ff 13 44   Wlw4wDl` .\0.ÿ.D 
    91 21 66 63 57 48 b9 0a                           ‘!fcWH¹.         
:29:08 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:08 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 52 00 50 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.R..P.......    
:29:08 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:08 Written  (COM19) 
    08 00 66 64 b9 6a 0c 00 04 6f b9 6a 14 00 b9 0a   ..fd¹j...o¹j..¹. 
    1c 00 0c 60 84 00 b9 6a                           ...`„.¹j         
:29:10 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:10 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 6a 00 68 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.j..h.......    
:29:10 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:10 Written  (COM19) 
    04 00 38 6a 00 c4 61 92 fd cb 86 00 00 91 21   ..8j..Äa’ýË†..‘! 
    cb 86 00 00 91 21 cb 86                           Ë†..‘!Ë†         
:29:11 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:11 Written  (COM19) 
    a5 03 82 00 80 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.‚..€.......    
:29:11 Read  (COM19) 
    ac                                                ¬                
:29:11 Written  (COM19) 
    00 00 d4 21 92 fd 2c 80 00 10 37 92 37 d1 26 67   ..Ô!’ý,€..7’7Ñ&g
    c6 86 a2 cb f2 bc 38 a1                           Æ†¢Ëò¼8¡
:29:13 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:13 Written  (COM19)
    a5 03 9a 00 98 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.š..˜.......
:29:13 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:13 Written  (COM19)
    0c 00 34 a1 93 aa b9 a1 0c 00 9a 7c ff ff 04 7d   ..4¡“ª¹¡..š|ÿÿ.}
    f2 02 04 79 b1 7d fa 12                           ò..y±}ú.
:29:14 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:14 Written  (COM19)
    a5 03 b2 00 b0 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.²..°.......
:29:14 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:14 Written  (COM19)
    ff ff 00 00 08 70 00 40 0c 60 cb 00 b9 67 24 00   ÿÿ...p.@.`Ë.¹g$.
    0c 60 96 00 b9 67 24 00                           .`–.¹g$.
:29:15 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:15 Written  (COM19)
    a5 03 de 0c 00 c8 14 0d 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.Þ..È.......
:29:15 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:15 Written  (COM19)
    0c 60 68 00 b9 67 24 00 e1 f0 00 00               .`h.¹g$.áð..
:29:17 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:17 Written  (COM19)
    a5 03 01 04 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............
:29:17 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:17 Written  (COM19)
    04 10 00 60                                       ...`
:29:18 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:18 Written  (COM19)
    a5 01 7c 00 00 00 00 0c 00 71 00 00 00            ¥.|......q...
:29:18 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:18 Written  (COM19)
    a5 01 01 00 00 0c 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............
:29:18 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:18 Written  (COM19)
    a5 01 9d 00 00 8c 10 00 00 00 00 00 00            ¥...Œ.......
:29:18 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:18 Written  (COM19)
    a5 01 a8 00 00 ac 07 02 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.¨..¬.......
:29:19 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:19 Written  (COM19)
    a5 00 09 00 00 11 00 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............
:29:19 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:21 Read  (COM19)
    00 00 00 01                                       ....
:29:21 Written  (COM19)
    a5 00 14 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............
:29:21 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:23 Read  (COM19)
    00 00 00 01                                       ....
:29:23 Written  (COM19)
    a5 00 14 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 00 00 00            ¥............
:29:23 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:25 Read  (COM19)
    00 00 00 01                                       ....
:29:25 Written  (COM19)
    a5 01 10 00 00 00 14 00 00 01 04 00 00            ¥............
:29:25 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:25 Written  (COM19)
    a5 01 f2 00 00 0c 00 0c 00 61 2f 52 ef            ¥.ò......a/Rï
:29:25 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:25 Written  (COM19)
    a5 05 83 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 a1 07 00            ¥.ƒ...... ¡..
:29:25 Read  (COM19)
    ac                                                ¬
:29:25 Written  (COM19)
    a5 00 9c 00 00 8c 10 00 00 00 00 00 00            ¥.œ..Œ.......
:29:25 Read  (COM19)
    00                                                .
:29:25 - Close port COM19
```

if anyone has faced same situation before and has a solution then please let me know. Thanks